# Queries running longer after license upgrade

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-performance

We have been running SQL server 2012 Enterprise Evaluation version on our new DB server for last two weeks.
Things were working well for us until last night when we applied a SQL server 2012 standard license on this DB. We are seeing that after applying standard license  DB our queries are taking much longer time to execute. This is not just an issue with one or two queries we are seeing this behaviour for all queries.
Is this behaviour because of license changes? Is there any way I can confirm this is actually because of license change?

Answer (score 0):

It may very well be due to the license change.  SQL Server Standard edition has limits on the number of processors and amount of memory that it can use.  SQL Server Enterprise edition does not.  Here is a link to an article with the specifics:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993(v=sql.110).aspx

Verifying that would be a challenge, unless you have another server box available with comparable horsepower where you can install SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Evaluation and then do side-by-side comparisons.